# Error when creating seach filter from geojson

Tags: geojson, python-2.7, planet

I tried to read geojson object from .geojson and build search filter rather than set a static geojson_geometry variable. However, it did not work as it used to with the static variable. Win7 pro, Py 2.7.15 32bit. Below are the codes and error.

```
aoi = r"E:\PLANET_Py\multipart84.geojson"

with open(aoi) as f:
    data = json.load(f)   

for feature in data['features']:
    poly_type = feature['geometry']['type']
    coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
    geojson_geometry=json.dumps((feature['geometry']))

geometry_filter = {
  "type": "GeometryFilter",
  "field_name": "geometry",
  "config": geojson_geometry
}

t = dt.now()

y = t - timedelta(days=1)
yy = t - timedelta(days=7)  

# get images acquired within a date range from current date
date_range_filter = {
  "type": "DateRangeFilter",
  "field_name": "acquired",
  "config": {
    "gte": "%sT00:00:00.000Z" % (yy.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),
    "lte": "%sT00:00:00.000Z" % (y.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  }
}

# only get images which have <50% cloud coverage
cloud_cover_filter = {
  "type": "RangeFilter",
  "field_name": "cloud_cover",
  "config": {
    "lte": 0.5
  }
}

# combine our geo, date, cloud filters
combined_filter = {
  "type": "AndFilter",
  "config": [geometry_filter, date_range_filter, cloud_cover_filter]
}

search_result = requests.post(
    'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/quick-search',
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth('myAPIkey', ''),
    json=search_request)

print(json.dumps(search_result.json(), indent=1))
```

AND the error is:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(search_result.json(), indent=1))
{
 "field": {
  "filter.config.0.config": [
   {
    "message": "u'{\"type\": \"MultiPolygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[[176.46349778345987, -38.11473809258582], [176.46250239004382, -38.11601884487258], [176.4572092610443, -38.112539947133165], [176.45354029872024, -38.10990685811454], [176.45037426916238, -38.10994039692455], [176.4481870229376, -38.108336173676946], [176.44620341737033, -38.106249209991965], [176.4505735765721, -38.10296254706899], [176.46137920964145, -38.11140400374731], [176.46349778345987, -38.11473809258582]]], [[[176.45454303454335, -38.08318117683172], [176.45779400238163, -38.091368419149184], [176.45855077571625, -38.09462355135948], [176.45431160331216, -38.09427167466392], [176.4466842623444, -38.095628113517066], [176.4462098387771, -38.09355640167274], [176.4526823046912, -38.09169766808866], [176.45147933287407, -38.08696586891919], [176.4451995665532, -38.08810379555714], [176.44410615101478, -38.0856926990337], [176.45454303454335, -38.08318117683172]]]]}' is not of type 'object'"
   }
  ]
 }, 
 "general": []
}
```

I suspect that the unicode in python is problem

```
"u'{\"type\": \"MultiPolygon\", \"coordinates\":..........
```

But do not know how to avoid it. I thought using json.dumps() was enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
geojson_geometry=json.dumps((feature['geometry']))
```

to

```
geojson_geometry=feature['geometry']
```

In other words, don't pass in your geometry as a *string* but as an actual Python dictionary like the rest of the request.

Comment: Thanks bosth, I did get it work last night, exactly I do not need json.dumps() to make a string :) Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer as the correct solution if it is right.